# Stored Procedure giving different output than the exact same Select

Tags: sql, select, rowcount

I have an odd issue....when I execute the select statement on it's own - I get results AND a valid @@ROWCOUNT. But when I execute the Procedure, I get different (0) results.

This gives me no results and a zero rowcount when I exec it:

```
USE [DefaultServer]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [Example].[TEST]   
AS

select ItemNumber,Descr,Size as [PkgSize]
from ItemTable
where ItemNumber not in (select ItemNumber from AlternateItemTable) 
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

However, when I just highlight the actual select statement and execute it, I get the proper results:

```
select ItemNumber,Descr,Size as [PkgSize]
from ItemTable
where ItemNumber not in (select ItemNumber from AlternateItemTable) 
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're in the same database.
Maybe put a "USE [DefaultServer] GO" in before running the select.

We've all done that befoer ;)

Comment: SQL Server I presume? Also, add a minimum dataset that showcases the problem. Read this for a good way on how to provide that: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). GL!

Comment: I was in the correct database, but there were exact copies of the tables in other schemas... once I fully qualified them, it was all good. Thanks for your help guys.